# can not exclude class from css * selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply a style on all children of a class except `.fixedsize` children:

```css
    .inner *:not(.fixedsize){
        max-width:100%
    }
    
    .fixedsize > *{
    max-width:none
    }
```

```html
    <div class="inner">
        <div>
        <div id="map" class="fixedsize">
           inspect the map here
           <div id="childOfMap">inspect the child of map here</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It seems not working.  How can I exclude it and all of its children from * selector?

**Edit:**
When I inspect the main element (map) in stackoverflow snippet it has no `max-width:100%` and this is ok. But in runtime and perhaps a more complex codes when I inspect the map, It has `max-width:100%` calculated from this * selector.

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: all children --> actually it's only one child

Comment: Your CSS should work with the HTML you've given, but keep in mind that you're not selecting all children, you're selecting all descendants. `.inner>*:not(.fixedsize)` would be all children. This might make a difference in many situations.

Comment: Thank you. How do I exclude fixedsize and all of its children? please postas answer so I can accept it. @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Your CSS works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/xzo451ft/

Comment: The fiddle above is not a general solution. please check its update: https://jsfiddle.net/xzo451ft/1/ @RezaSaadati

Comment: you code is working fine, but the background is applied to the first div, so you see the red of the container

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/xzo451ft/2/

Comment: still not clear what you want to achieve .. edit your question with a full code that show the issue and also describe what you want to have instead.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `:not()` selector is more specific, so you need to increase the specifity of the other selector or use `!important`

```css
.inner *:not(.fixedsize) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
/*Adding not() will make the specifity of this one higher*/
.fixedsize *:not(#randomId) {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div>
    <div id="map" class="fixedsize">
      no border
      <div id="childOfMap">no border <span>here also</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>some other content<span>here</span></div>
</div>
```

With `!important`:

```css
.inner *:not(.fixedsize) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.fixedsize * {
  border:none!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div>
    <div id="map" class="fixedsize">
      no border
      <div id="childOfMap">no border <span>here also</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>some other content<span>here</span></div>
</div>
```